# python 3 aiml error WARNING No match found for input

Tags: python-3.x, aiml

I am facing issues while using amil. i have downloded it from https://github.com/paulovn/python-aiml . when i use the below code it is throwing me match not found error.

```
import aiml
k = aiml.Kernel()
k.learn("std-startup.xml")
k.respond("load aiml b")
while True: print (k.respond(input("> "))
```

i have placed all .aiml files and .xml files in my working directory. my folder structure is below

```
AIML
  main
    standard
      *.amil files
    ai.py
    std-startup.xml
```

in std-startup.xml, i have changed the path as well, don't know where i am going wrong

```
<aiml version="1.0">
<!-- This category works with the Standard AIML Set -->
<category>
<pattern>LOAD AIML B</pattern>
<template>
<!-- Load standard AIML set -->

<learn>main/standard/std-*.aiml</learn>

</template>
</category>

</aiml>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in: *.amil files

It should be *.aiml files